# Загрузка изображений на сервер (ASP.NET)

Tags: c#, asp.net, http, ftp, fileupload

У меня написан веб-сервис (ASP.NET приложение, крутится на IIS), который обрабатывает присылаемые с клиента изображения и отправляет результат в виде XML-файла обратно. Изображения должны посылаться на сервер как через браузер с помощью формы, так и через клиентское приложение(C#, без интерфейса и ввода/вывода).

Какой способ передачи лучше всего подходит для моего случая, использовать HTTP или FTP?

На данный момент я только знаю, что есть функция FileUpload() формы, но там не понятно как ее использовать для несколько загружаемых файлов.
Что касается клиент-приложения, есть ли какие-нибудь готовые фреймворки для обмена данными?

Пока что нашел две интересные статьи на эту тему:

FTP: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229715(v=vs.110).aspx

HTTP: http://jqueryasp.net/upload-multiple-image-file-progress-bar-asp-net-using-jquery/

Answer (score 1):

Если сервер у вас уже есть - то он ожидает какого-то конкретного способа передачи данных. Судя по ASP.NET - это HTTP.

Захостить под ASP.NET/IIS приложение, которое будет обрабатывать FTP-запросы, у вас скорее всего не получится.

Для клиентского приложения - есть стандартный [`WebClient.UploadFile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36s52zhs(v=vs.110).aspx).

Для страницы - та самая ссылка, которую вы привели, если нужен множественный upload.